# Rendering inline styles based on prop in Rect

Tags: reactjs

I am building a reusable component for a texfield that uses two different inline styles depending on location

```
style={{marginTop:15, marginBottom:35}} // the first of type needs a top margin
style={{marginTop:0, marginBottom:35}} // all others
```

I hate having to specify this every time I use the component. Essentially I would like the second style to be defaulted and the first one to be accessed by a boolean prop like firstOfType ={true}...that would make firstOfType={false} as the default so I don't have to even specify it in my view.

I'm having trouble working with this since style requires double brackets and a condition inside the brackets didn't work either. Mind you, I'm new to react. So bear with me here. This is probably very simple.

This is what my component looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TextField from 'material-ui-next/TextField';

const CMInputField = ({label, value, onChange, rows, margin, style}, context) => {
    return (
        <TextField
            label={context.t(label)}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            InputLabelProps={{shrink: true}}
            style={{marginTop:0, marginBottom:35}} //the defaulted one
            fullWidth
            multiline
            rows={rows}
            margin={margin}/> 
    );
};

CMInputField.defaultProps = {
    margin: 'normal',
    fullwidth: true,
    multiline: false,
    firstOfType: false,
};

CMInputField.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    value: PropTypes.object,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    style: PropTypes.object,
    fullwidth: PropTypes.bool,
    multiline: PropTypes.bool,
    rows: PropTypes.string,
    margin: PropTypes.string,
    firstOfType: PropTypes.bool,
};

CMInputField.contextTypes = {
    t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default CMInputField;
```

And I would use it this way:

```
<CMInputField
    label="First Input"
    value="Hello"
    onChange={this.myFunction}
    firstOfType/> 

<CMInputField
    label="Second Input"
    value="Hello Again"
    onChange={this.myFunction2}/>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you try this way

```
const CMInputField = ({label, value, onChange, rows, margin, style}, context) => {
    let textFieldStyle = {"marginTop":0, "marginBottom":35};
    if(firstOfType) textFieldStyle= {"marginTop":15, "marginBottom":35};
    return (
        <TextField
            label={context.t(label)}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            InputLabelProps={{shrink: true}}
            style={textFieldStyle} //the defaulted one
            fullWidth
            multiline
            rows={rows}
            margin={margin}/> 
    );
};

<CMInputField
    label="First Input"
    value="Hello"
    onChange={this.myFunction}
    firstOfType={true}/> 

<CMInputField
    label="Second Input"
    value="Hello Again"
    onChange={this.myFunction2}
    firstOfType={false}/>
```

Comment: I like where your mind is going but it fails compilation due to double declaration of "style"

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice that thanks for correcting. I updated my answer now you can try

Comment: BOOM!!! NAILED IT! Thanks man. I knew it had to be easy...for you guys anyway. :)

Comment: Glad to help :)